# How many ways are there for 10 people to have five simultaneous telephone conversations?

Tags: combinatorics

So what I'm thinking is 
$$
\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2} \ldots \binom{2}{2}
$$

But that's far from what the answer is.

Comment: Number of combinations of 2 from 10, divided by 2, since the conversation is order-independent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably this is to be interpreted as asking for the number of different ways to pair up $10$ people. Imagine numbering them $1$ through $10$. There are $9$ choices for the person to be paired with Nr. $1$. Once that pair has been determined, find a partner for the lowest-numbered person remaining; that will be either Nr. $2$ or Nr. $3$, depending on who Nr. $1$’s partner is. Either way, there are $7$ possible choices for his partner, because $3$ people are out of the running: he himself, and the first pair. That gives us $9\cdot7$ ways to choose the first two pairs. Now find a partner for the lowest-numbered person remaining: there are $5$ available choices, since we have to exclude the first two pairs and the person for whom we’re finding a partner. Putting the pieces together, we can form the first three pairs in $9\cdot7\cdot5$ ways.

Can you finish the analysis from there?

**Added:** Judging by your calculation, you’re thinking of choosing a pair, then a pair from the remaining $8$, and so on. The problem is that you might choose the same set of $5$ pairs in $5!$ different orders, so you’re overcounting by a factor of $5!$. And indeed,

$$\binom{10}2\binom82\dots\binom22=\frac{10!}{2^5}=5\cdot9\cdot4\cdot7\cdot3\cdot5\cdot2\cdot3\cdot1\cdot1=5!(9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1)\;.$$

Comment: This is so much more intuitive than the textbook solution: $(10!/(2!^5))/5!$ What's the reasoning for how they got this expression?

Comment: @Alan: Does the addition explain their calculation, or should I say a little more?

Comment: Yeah that explains it. Thanks for the intuitive explanation.

Comment: @Alan: You’re welcome!

Comment: For the answer involving $10!$, we line up the people ($10!$ ways to do this) and pair first with second, third with fourth, and so on. But interchanging first and second and/or third and fourth, and so on, gives same teams, so we are overcounting by a factor of $2^5$. So we divide by $2^5$ to compensate. Also, the same set of pairs can be selected in $5!$ ways, so need to further divide by $5!$.

Answer (score 5):

We assume that a telephone conversations involve two people. So the question comes down to finding how to divide a group of $10$ into $5$ groups of $2$.

Line up the people in order of height, or student number.

Person $1$ can choose her partner in $9$ ways. For each such choice, the first person in the list who has not yet been partnered can choose her partner in $7$ ways. Now the first person not yet partnered can choose her partner in $5$ ways, and so on.

So the total number of ways is $(9)(7)(5)(3)(1)$.

**Another way:** We choose $2$ people from the $10$, then choose $2$ people from the remaining $8$, and so on.

There are $\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}$ ways to do this.  But the number just calculated grossly overcounts the number of ways to divide our people into telephone teams of $2$. This is because the product just obtained counts the each pairing $5!$ times, since it takes order of choosing into account. To get the right count, we must therefore divide by $5!%.

**Remark:** There are many other reasonable ways of doing the counting. In this problem, it is all too easy to overcount.

Answer (score 1):

The question is that of the number of [perfect matchings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching) in a complete graph on $10$ vertices. The number $M(n)$ of such matchings in a complete graph on $2n$ vertices satisfies the recurion $M(n)=(2n-1)M(n-1)$ (with $M(0)=1$) since there are $2n-1$ candidates to be matched to the first vertex and after that it remains to choose a perfect matching on the complete graph on the remaining $2(n-1)$ points. Thus $M(n)=(2n-1)\times(2n-3)\times\cdots\times3\times1$, a number that is denoted by some people as $(2n-1)!!$ (in spite of the ambiguity of this notation with "factorial of the factorial"). This number comes up in very many problemns, see for instance the descriptions in [OEIS A001147](http://oeis.org/A001147). One that seems t be missing from that list is that it is the dimension of the [Brauer algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_algebra) for $n$.

Of course you can compute $9\times7\times5\times3\times1=945$ without difficulty.